# Expressjs Is there way to make file only accessible to website and not to users?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an express server and I have some files that I site needs to connect to the firebase, but I need to make them available only for my site code and not to users because they could see all my credentials. Is there way to do it?

Comment: No, it's impossible.

Comment: You can only keep secrets from users _on_ your server. All your config and connection should probably be located there.